# How can I use the administration theme for the user/%/edit page?

Tags: 7, theming

How can I get the *user/%/edit* page to use the admin theme that is used for the rest of the site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That path is already one that will use the admin theme *if* the current user has the correct permissions to access it.

Try going to http://mysite.com/admin/people/permissions and checking the "View the administration theme" permission for the roles you wish to be able to use the admin theme.

It'll definitely work as the User module implements [`hook_admin_paths()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_admin_paths/7) to define that path as an admin page:

```
function user_admin_paths() {
  $paths = array(
    'user/*/cancel' => TRUE, 
    'user/*/edit' => TRUE, 
    'user/*/edit/*' => TRUE,
  );
  return $paths;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it was so helpful! Also themekey module can help but Code is always faster! thanks

Comment: also we can use 'hook_admin_paths_alter()'